# CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed in react native on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I started having this error suddenly for no apparent reason. The app runs completely fine and at some point in time after I refresh the app (using `hot reloading in expo`), I get this error and I need to restart the packager and then the app works again.

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

```
 1: 00007FF63201F04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCId
leTimeHandler+5114
 2: 00007FF631FFA0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF631FFAA30 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF6322820EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF63228201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF6327A2BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
 7: 00007FF6327A10CB v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2651
 8: 00007FF63235CA3B v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap+59
 9: 00007FF63235F4ED v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString+77
10: 00007FF632569AA8 v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint+536
11: 00007FF63227582B v8::internal::StringHasher::UpdateIndex+219
12: 00007FF63229AB26 v8::String::Utf8Length+22
13: 00007FF631F518B7 v8::internal::LookupIterator::index+37719
14: 00007FF631F4DAF3 v8::internal::LookupIterator::index+21907
15: 00007FF631F4A49A v8::internal::LookupIterator::index+7994
16: 00007FF6327FC122 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+59890
17: 00007FF6327FD5AD v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+65149
18: 00007FF6327FC606 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61142
19: 00007FF6327FC4EB v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+60859
20: 00000223BE85C5C1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that memory allocation has occurred beyond the node's heap memory allocation limit size.

Set the max_old_space_size option to increase the size of the heap memory allocation limit.

You can use `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` since **node v8.0** instead.

Comment: But this problem occurs in my react native app. I don't think I can apply your solution there.

Comment: `react-native` and `node` are closely related. All modules are related to `node`.